# Getting wrong position of items in filtered list view

Tags: android, listview, filter

I have a list, that filters the data when user enter the search string. It opens new activity when user clicked the search item. The Problem is it opens the wrong intent. When user clicked the item, the position changes as it is filtered list view. It always returns first item's intent as the matched search result always displays first. I am missing a small part of it, please any help will be appreciated.

Here is my **Custom Adapter**

```
public class Searchitemadapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
 private Home activity;
 private FriendFilter friendFilter;
 private ArrayList<B_allProducts> friendList;
 private ArrayList<B_allProducts> filteredList;

public Searchitemadapter(Home activity, ArrayList<B_allProducts> friendList) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.friendList = friendList;
    this.filteredList = friendList;

    getFilter();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return filteredList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    final B_allProducts user = (B_allProducts) getItem(position);

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_container_searchitem, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_search_pname);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // get view holder back
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(user.getProductName());

    return view;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (friendFilter == null) {
        friendFilter = new FriendFilter();
    }

    return friendFilter;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}
private class FriendFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0) {
            ArrayList<B_allProducts> tempList = new ArrayList<B_allProducts>();

            for (B_allProducts user : friendList) {
                if (user.getProductName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())
                        ||user.getProductKeywordG().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())
                        ||user.getProductKeyword().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                {
                    tempList.add(user);
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = friendList.size();
            filterResults.values = friendList;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredList = (ArrayList<B_allProducts>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my **List View onItemClickListener**

```
 lvsearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            String pos = aphashmap.get(position).get("ProductID");
            Intent i = new Intent(SearchableActivity.this, DisplaySingleProduct.class);
            i.putExtra("ProductID",pos);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be use parent object and getAdapter() method to get right position.

For Example;

```
lvsearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        int positionOfItem=parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)
        String pos = aphashmap.get(positionOfItem).get("ProductID");
        Intent i = new Intent(SearchableActivity.this, DisplaySingleProduct.class);
        i.putExtra("ProductID",pos);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not working mate... besides `.getItem()` is an object not `int`

Comment: Debug and check in evaluating

Comment: It is returning value with the BeanClass.B_AllProducts@someint (my getter, setter class). as my `.getItem()` returns object. how to convert that object to particular ProductID?

Comment: Casting to Modelclass and get id of products Id

Comment: ((Your_model) parent.getAdapter().getItem(positio)).getProductId();